# Show that the derivative of a convex function is zero as $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}{f(x)}=A$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is a convex function and differentiable everywhere on $(0, \infty)$ and satisfies
>   $$\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}{f(x)}=A$$
>   where $A$ is an arbitrary real number. Show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f'(x)}=0$$

**My attempt:** Suppose $f'(x_0)>0$ for $x_0 \in (0, \infty)$ such that
$$f(x) \geq f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
Taking limit that tends to infinity on both sides obtain
$$A=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} \geq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{[f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)]}=\infty$$
which contradicts the fact that $A$ is finite. Similar to the case when $f'(x_0)<0$, Hence, $f'(x_0)=0$ for $x_0 \in (0, \infty)$. Take $x_0 \rightarrow \infty$ and it follows the conclusion.

**Note:** Any constant function $f$ is a trivial case on this question.

In this question, I illustrated an example $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and referring to  its geometry interpretation of derivative, but I hope to know that if my attempt is wrong as I make $x_0\rightarrow \infty$ in my last progess, which is weird and correct it.

Comment: If $f'(x_0) < 0$, then the limit on the right side will be $-\infty$ not $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had edited my assumption, that is, $f'(x_0)>0$.

Comment: If $f'(x_0) < 0$, then the limit on the right side is $-\infty$ and there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You've successfully come up with a contradiction if $f'(x_0) > 0$ for any $x_0 \in (0,\infty)$. Therefore, $f'(x) \le 0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Now, since $f$ is convex, i.e. $f'(x)$ is increasing. Since $f'(x)$ is increasing and bounded above by $0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)$ exists. Can you find a contradiction if this limit is less than zero?

Comment: If the limit is less than 0, then the function is monotonically decreasing on the open interval $(0, \infty)$, which contradicts the assumption that $f$ is increasing. Something like that?

Comment: I have some idea came across my mind: since the limit exists when $x$ tends to infinity, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{f'(x)}=0$, otherwise $f$ is bounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For a convex differentiable function we canwrite $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} f'(t)\, dt$. The hypothesis implies that $\int_0^{x} f'(t)\, dt$ remains bounded as $ x\to \infty$. Note that $f'$ is increasing, so it has a (finite or infinite) limit as $ x\to \infty$. If the limit is not $0$ you get a contradiction to the fact that $\int_0^{x} f'(t)\, dt$ remains bounded as $ x\to \infty$. (The integral goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ according as $\lim f'(x) >0$ or $\lim f'(x) <0$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: once define $x=x_0+1$ therefore$$f(x_0+1)-f(x_0)\ge f'(x_0)$$and tend $x_0$ to $\infty$. Another time let $x=x_0-1$ therefore $$f(x_0-1)-f(x_0)\ge -f'(x_0)$$and let $x_0\to \infty$. Then conclude what you want using squeeze theorem.